# external signature results in corrupted pdf after signing

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature

I am trying to sign a pdf document from a 3rd party signature provider.
I send them the document hash, after creating the empty signature and they send a timestamp token (we agreed it would be a timestamp signature) and I add the signature back into the pdf. the api call to get the timestmp and crl and ocsp goes well, but once I generate the pdf with the signature, adobe says the signature is not valid and the error is:

Error during signature verification.

Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data.
Support Information: SigDict /Contents illegal data

this is the current code:

signatureprovider.java

```
    public ByteArrayOutputStream sign(byte[] src, Rectangle rect, int signPage) throws Exception {
    log.info("I am in the signing method");
    ByteArrayOutputStream dest = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfDocumentHandler handler = new PdfDocumentHandler(new ByteArrayInputStream(src), dest);
    handler.prepareForSigning(rect, signPage);
    TrustedTimestampService service = new TrustedTimestampService();
    SignResponseWrapper response = new SignResponseWrapper();
    response = service.signHash(handler.getEncodedDocumentHash());
    String timestampToken = response.getSignResponse().getSignatureObject().getOther().getScSignatureObjects().getScExtendedSignatureObject().getTimestamp().getRFC3161TimeStampToken();
    List<String> encodedCrlEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
    encodedCrlEntries.add(response.getSignResponse().getOptionalOutputs().getScRevocationInformation().getScCRLs().getScCRL());
    List<String> encodedOcspEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
    encodedOcspEntries.add(response.getSignResponse().getOptionalOutputs().getScRevocationInformation().getScOCSPs().getScOCSP());
    byte[] signed = handler.createSignedPdf(Base64.getDecoder().decode(timestampToken), 15000, encodedCrlEntries, encodedOcspEntries);
    dest.flush();
    dest.write(signed);
    handler.close();
    return dest;
}
```

I will avoid adding the service, it simply sends the hash and gets the tokens
pdfdocumenthandler.java

public PdfDocumentHandler(InputStream inputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {
this.inputStream = inputStream;
this.outputStream = outputStream;

```
}

public void prepareForSigning(Rectangle rect, int signPage)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    inMemoryStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inMemoryStream.write(StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(inputStream));

    boolean hasSignature = hasDocumentSignature();
    pdfReader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(inMemoryStream.toByteArray()), new ReaderProperties());
    inMemoryStream.reset();
    pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(inMemoryStream, new WriterProperties().addXmpMetadata().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_0));
    StampingProperties stampingProperties = new StampingProperties();
    pdfSigner = new PdfDocumentSigner(pdfReader, inMemoryStream, hasSignature ? stampingProperties.useAppendMode() : stampingProperties);

    pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance()
        .setReason("myreason")
        .setLocation("mylocation")
        .setContact("mycontact")
        .setPageRect(rect)
        .setPageNumber(signPage)
        .setSignatureCreator("creator");

    pdfSigner.setFieldName("digitalSig");
    try {
        imgStorage = new ImageStorage();
        ImageData imgData = ImageDataFactory.create(Base64.getDecoder().decode(imgStorage.getimgData().getBytes()));
        pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance().setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
        pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance().setSignatureGraphic(imgData);
    } catch(Exception e){
        pdfSigner.getSignatureAppearance().setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
    }
    
    Map<PdfName, PdfObject> signatureDictionary = new HashMap<>();
    signatureDictionary.put(PdfName.Filter, PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite);
    signatureDictionary.put(PdfName.SubFilter, PdfName.ETSI_RFC3161);

    Calendar signDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    pdfSigner.setSignDate(signDate);

    PdfHashSignatureContainer hashSignatureContainer = new PdfHashSignatureContainer("SHA-512", new PdfDictionary(signatureDictionary));
    documentHash = pdfSigner.computeHash(hashSignatureContainer, 15_000);
    log.info("prepared document - outputstream: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray()));
    log.info("prepared document - inmemorystream: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inMemoryStream.toByteArray()));
    
}

public byte[] createSignedPdf(byte[] externalSignature, int estimatedSize, List<String> encodedCrlEntries,
                            List<String> encodedOcspEntries) {
    if (pdfSigner.getCertificationLevel() == PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not apply signature because source file contains a certification that does not allow "
                                                   + "any changes to the document with id %s"));
    }
    if (estimatedSize < externalSignature.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Not enough space for signature in the document. The estimated size needs to be " +
                                                   " %d bytes.", externalSignature.length));
    }

    try {
        pdfSigner.signWithAuthorizedSignature(new PdfSignatureContainer(externalSignature), estimatedSize);

        if (null != encodedCrlEntries || null!=encodedOcspEntries) {
            extendDocumentWithCrlOcspMetadata(encodedCrlEntries, encodedOcspEntries);
        } else {
            log.info("No CRL and OCSP entries were received to be embedded into the PDF");
            outputStream.write(inMemoryStream.toByteArray());
        }
        //outputStream.write(inMemoryStream.toByteArray());
        closeResource(inMemoryStream);
        closeResource(outputStream);
        log.info("complete document - outputstream: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray()));
        log.info("complete document - inmemorystream: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inMemoryStream.toByteArray()));
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to embed the signature in the document"), e);
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}

private void extendDocumentWithCrlOcspMetadata(List<String> encodedCrlEntries, List<String> encodedOcspEntries) {
    if (pdfSigner.getCertificationLevel() == PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not apply revocation information (LTV) to the DSS Dictionary. Document contains a " +
                                                   "certification that does not allow any changes"));
    }
    log.info("document without crl and ocsp - outputstream: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray()));
    log.info("document without crl and ocsp - inmemorystream: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(inMemoryStream.toByteArray()));
    List<byte[]> crl = mapEncodedEntries(encodedCrlEntries, this::mapEncodedCrl);
    List<byte[]> ocsp = mapEncodedEntries(encodedOcspEntries, this::mapEncodedOcsp);

    try (InputStream documentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inMemoryStream.toByteArray());
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(documentStream);
         PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
         PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader, writer, new StampingProperties().preserveEncryption().useAppendMode())) {
        LtvVerification validation = new LtvVerification(pdfDocument);
        List<String> signatureNames = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument).getSignatureNames();
        String signatureName = signatureNames.get(signatureNames.size() - 1);
        boolean isSignatureVerificationAdded = validation.addVerification(signatureName, ocsp, crl, null);
        validation.merge();
        logSignatureVerificationInfo(isSignatureVerificationAdded);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to embed the signature(s) in the document(s) and close the streams"));
    }
    
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getEncodedDocumentHash() {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(documentHash);
}

private void logSignatureVerificationInfo(boolean isSignatureVerificationAdded) {
    if (isSignatureVerificationAdded) {
        log.info("Merged LTV validation information to the output stream");
    } else {
        log.warn("Failed to merge LTV validation information to the output stream");
    }
}

private List<byte[]> mapEncodedEntries(List<String> encodedEntries, Function<String, byte[]> mapperFunction) {
    return Objects.nonNull(encodedEntries)
           ? encodedEntries.stream().map(mapperFunction).collect(Collectors.toList())
           : Collections.emptyList();
}

private byte[] mapEncodedCrl(String encodedCrl) {
    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedCrl))) {
        X509CRL x509crl = (X509CRL) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCRL(inputStream);
        logCrlInfo(x509crl);
        return x509crl.getEncoded();
    } catch (IOException | CertificateException | CRLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to map the received encoded CRL entry"), e);
    }
}

private byte[] mapEncodedOcsp(String encodedOcsp) {
    try (InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedOcsp))) {
        OCSPResp ocspResp = new OCSPResp(inputStream);
        BasicOCSPResp basicResp = (BasicOCSPResp) ocspResp.getResponseObject();
        logOcspInfo(ocspResp, basicResp);
        return basicResp.getEncoded();
    } catch (IOException | OCSPException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Failed to map the received encoded OCSP entry"), e);
    }
}

private void logCrlInfo(X509CRL x509crl) {
    int revokedCertificatesNo = Objects.isNull(x509crl.getRevokedCertificates()) ? 0 : x509crl.getRevokedCertificates().size();

    String message = "Embedding CRL response... ["
                     + "IssuerDN: " + x509crl.getIssuerX500Principal() + " "
                     + "This update: " + x509crl.getThisUpdate() + " "
                     + "Next update: " + x509crl.getNextUpdate() + " "
                     + "No. of revoked certificates: " + revokedCertificatesNo
                     + "]";
    log.info(message);
}

private void logOcspInfo(OCSPResp ocspResp, BasicOCSPResp basicResp) {
    SingleResp response = basicResp.getResponses()[0];
    BigInteger serialNumber = response.getCertID().getSerialNumber();
    X509CertificateHolder firstCertificate = basicResp.getCerts()[0];

    String message = "Embedding OCSP response... ["
                     + "Status: " + (ocspResp.getStatus() == 0 ? "OK" : "NOK") + " "
                     + "Produced at: " + basicResp.getProducedAt() + " "
                     + "This update: " + response.getThisUpdate() + " "
                     + "Next update: " + response.getNextUpdate() + " "
                     + "X509 cert issuer: " + firstCertificate.getIssuer() + " "
                     + "X509 cert subject: " + firstCertificate.getSubject() + " "
                     + "Certificate ID: " + serialNumber.toString() + "(" + serialNumber.toString(16).toUpperCase() + ")"
                     + "]";
    log.info(message);
}

private boolean hasDocumentSignature() throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(inMemoryStream.toByteArray());
         PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is, new ReaderProperties());
         PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader)) {
        SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
        return signatureUtil.getSignatureNames().size() > 0;
    }
}
```

pdfdocumentsigner.java

```
public class PdfDocumentSigner extends PdfSigner {

public PdfDocumentSigner(PdfReader reader, OutputStream outputStream, boolean properties) throws IOException {
    super(reader, outputStream, properties);
}

public byte[] computeHash(IExternalSignatureContainer externalHashContainer, int estimatedSize) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    if (closed) {
        throw new PdfException(PdfException.ThisInstanceOfPdfSignerAlreadyClosed);
    }

    PdfSignature signatureDictionary = new PdfSignature();
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = getSignatureAppearance();
    signatureDictionary.setReason(appearance.getReason());
    signatureDictionary.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
    signatureDictionary.setSignatureCreator(appearance.getSignatureCreator());
    signatureDictionary.setContact(appearance.getContact());
    signatureDictionary.setDate(new PdfDate(getSignDate()));
    externalHashContainer.modifySigningDictionary(signatureDictionary.getPdfObject());
    cryptoDictionary = signatureDictionary;

    Map<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<>();
    exc.put(PdfName.Contents, estimatedSize * 2 + 2);
    preClose(exc);

    InputStream dataRangeStream = getRangeStream();
    return externalHashContainer.sign(dataRangeStream);
}

public void signWithAuthorizedSignature(IExternalSignatureContainer externalSignatureContainer, int estimatedSize)
    throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    InputStream dataRangeStream = getRangeStream();
    byte[] authorizedSignature = externalSignatureContainer.sign(dataRangeStream);

    if (estimatedSize < authorizedSignature.length) {
        throw new IOException(String.format("Not enough space. The estimated signature size [%d bytes] is less than the received authorized "
                                            + "signature [%d bytes] which needs to be embedded into the document.", estimatedSize,
                                            authorizedSignature.length));
    }

    byte[] paddedSignature = new byte[estimatedSize];
    System.arraycopy(authorizedSignature, 0, paddedSignature, 0, authorizedSignature.length);

    PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
    dic2.put(PdfName.Contents, new PdfString(paddedSignature).setHexWriting(true));
    close(dic2);

    closed = true;
}
```

I have been looking and it does seem like I am not missing anything, can anyone please help me figure this out?
here vis the final pdf sample

[sample pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tJDN1JeOsjq8PqgI1QOzS2vOC2O8JxoI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share an example pdf signed by your code for analysis.

Comment: thank you, I just added the document

Comment: Your code is inconsistent. In `prepareForSigning` you instantiate a `PdfDocumentSigner` with a `PdfWriter` argument (`new PdfDocumentSigner(pdfReader, pdfWriter, false)`) but the `PdfDocumentSigner` you show only comes with a `PdfDocumentSigner(PdfReader reader, OutputStream outputStream, boolean properties)` constructor. Thus, please have a look at your code again and check whether you simply forgot to copy&paste some code or whether you actually use a different `PdfDocumentSigner` class.

Comment: That been said your example file looks like an originally probably correctly signed PDF was manipulated regularly (i.e. not in append mode) which moved objects (resulting in the signed byte ranges entry gap not holding the signature container anymore) and so completely invalidated the signature. Your code appears to attempt to use append mode everywhere, so that behavior does not match either.

Comment: That being said, I wouldn't recommend using the architecture in your code. `PdfSigner` is not really meant to be derived from. Your code would IMO be much cleaner if you used a standard `PdfSigner` with its `signExternalContainer` method for your first step with your `PdfHashSignatureContainer`, then requested the signature container from the service, and then eventually used a `PdfDocument` with the static `PdfSigner.signDeferred` method to inject the signature container into your PDF.

Comment: I set the append mode when I create the signer, is there somewhere else I should use it? also, the signDeferred method wants a string for the name of the field, would that be the signature name?

Comment: *"I set the append mode when I create the signer, is there somewhere else I should use it?"* - You in particular also use append mode in `extendDocumentWithCrlOcspMetadata`. The example looks as if that was missing, though. *"the signDeferred method wants a string for the name of the field, would that be the signature name"* - the signature field name.

Comment: right, but I thought I needed to use the append mode for adding the crls and ocsps, is that not the case?

Comment: *"but I thought I needed to use the append mode for adding the crls and ocsps, is that not the case?"* - Yes, you do. Always use append mode when dealing with PDFs that are signed. But in your example PDF that apparently did not happen, its a single-revision PDF including CRLs etc.. Thus, it looks like CRLs and OCSP responses have been added with different code than the code you posted. As already commented above, there are more discrepancies.

Comment: the code is that, it seems very strange, I will try the changes you suggested, thank you

Comment: Im having major issues with those suggestions, but I noticed that changing the instantiation of the pdfsigner to: 
pdfSigner = new PdfDocumentSigner(pdfReader, inMemoryStream, true)
changed nothing in the behaviour of the service

Comment: *"I noticed that"* - Well, that's not the point. If the original code you posted in your question did successfully compile and you did not forget to copy&paste a constructor accepting a `PdfWriter`, then apparently your code uses a different `PdfDocumentSigner` than you think; either simply a different version of the class you think or a completely different class altogether. Have you checked imports etc? Alternatively your compile attempts simply failed and you ran an earlier version of the whole code (I don't know your tool stack, so this might happen without being too obvious).

Comment: There is no import because the pdfsigner is in the same package. However I did a test with the pdfsigner declared like this:

    private com.mydomain.myservice.service.PdfDocumentSigner pdfSigner;

and nothing changed; I am using itextpdf 7.0.5 and I haven't slept trying to figure this out

Comment: That you used a non-existing constructor is only part of the weirdness. Another part is that your example file is a single revision file while according to your code it should have two revisions. In the end this means that I cannot be sure about anything in your code.

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your code? E.g. for starters by not calling `extendDocumentWithCrlOcspMetadata` at all? Have you tried saving intermediate file states, e.g. whenever you have it as a byte[]? Have you checked whether you do see the log outputs of your code? Also have you tried switching to a current iText version? 7.0.5 is somewhat old and still has some issues stemming from the iText 5/iText 7 architecture break.

Comment: I did update itext to 7.1.14 and after fixing some old "cell.add("text")" the service is up and running again, but the output was still the same.
In the logs I could see all the crls and ocsps info, and, according to the log at least, the ltv validation was successfully merged into the document. 
I also tried to comment out the call to the method that adds those entries to the pdf and still nothing.
I added the logs for the document at every stage, but all the bytearraysoutputstreams seem to be empty, I edited the pdfdocumenthandler class in the question to show the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(inMemoryStream, new WriterProperties().addXmpMetadata().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_0));
```

that was the issue, after changing it to

```
pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(inMemoryStream, new WriterProperties().addXmpMetadata().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_3));
```

it worked perfectly